# Laravel, checking condition if request is not null

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form in Laravel and the submission and validation works, but I'm doing custom validation to check the data against the database (for sanitization) as well.

The issue is, I only want to do this validation IF each of the fields is filled out. In other words, if an input isn't required thus not filled out, I don't want it to fail because of it not matching data in the database.

For instance, I have a form input on my blade:

```
<td>{!! Form::select('productNumber',  $img->productNumber) !!}</td>
```

and in the controller I'm checking this against the service to make sure it's valid data

```
if(!$productCheckService->validGroupCode($request->productNumber))
        return back()->withErrors("Invalid group: ".$request->productNumber);
```

This works if filled out, but if the field is empty I want to bypass that check. In other words, the field isn't required so the data validity check shouldn't be required on a possibly null/empty field

I'm doing this below but it still is failing if it's empty for some reason. Am I totally missing something? I would think that checking that it's not empty before the check should suffice.

```
if(!empty($request->productNumber))
 if(!$productCheckService->validGroupCode($request->productNumber))
        return back()->withErrors("Invalid group: ".$request->productNumber);
```

Comment: `if ($request->filled("productNumber"))` perhaps?

Comment: I just realized part of the problem is it's a select now, not a text. So my default select option value is " ", and then "2' up to "8". So I think now I want to check and say, if $request->productNumber value = " "

Comment: That's what `filled()` does; it checks if there is a non-empty value.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know if it would work for select. Let me try this now, thanks!

Comment: It says method filled doesn't exist, I wonder if it's my version. I'm using 5.2, checking now to see if it works the same way there

Comment: Looking at the manual, it didn't appear until 5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel 'sometimes' attributes, so if your field is not present in request array it will bypass from validation.

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
'productNumber' => 'sometimes|required|number',
```

]);

Comment: I've actually done this to keep the field from being required, but what I have above is my custom validation that checks against the database. IN other words, the 'Group' Input isn't currently required, but even if it's empty my site is checking for it in the database and failing (since it can't find an empty result). I just want to skip this validation if it's empty

Comment: Did you check the value of productNumber coming from client side when empty? try dd($request->productNumber)

Comment: Yes and it dumps an empty value if I check it

Comment: Did you tried trim? !empty(trim($request->productNumber))

Comment: Ooh I think it's because it's coming from a select box which is never technically empty